# Can you suggest a free Cloud hosting provider?

Tags: java, cloud

I want to host a sample java web application(if possible any DB) for my learning, can you suggest any free cloud hosting providers?

Comment: Hello and welcome to SO. Note that this is not a shopping recommendation site, but a site for Q&A *directly* related to programming.

Answer (score 2):

Try [Google App Engine for Java](http://code.google.com/appengine/docs/java/overview.html) -- you can either use GAE-specific code or run most regular WAR files there. Pay special attentation to the [restrictions of the sandbox](http://code.google.com/appengine/docs/java/runtime.html) your code runs in on GAE.

Answer (score -4):

Try [a free trial with Microsoft's Azure](http://www.microsoft.com/windowsazure/free-trial/)